# Is this set a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose I have the following set:

$V = \{ P \in \mathbb{C}[x] : P(x)=P(1+i-x) \}$

I want to figure out if $V$ is a vector space, now the issue I'm having is understanding what $V$ actually is, specifically the  $P(x)=P(1+i-x)$ part doesn't make much sense, the only thing I can tell from the previous expression is that it holds for $x = \frac{1+i}{2}$.

That being said my, (failed) attempt to solve it goes as follows:

let $P_1 \in V$, also let  $P_2 \in V$, therefore is $\mu P_1 + \lambda P_2 \in V$? ($\mu , \lambda$ are scalars)

$\mu P_1 + \lambda P_2 = \mu P_1(1+i-x) + \lambda P_2(1+i-x) = P_3$

let's hypothesize $P_3 \in V$, hence

$P_3(x)=P_3(1+i-x) \Rightarrow (\mu P_1 + \lambda P_2)(x) = (\mu P_1 + \lambda P_2)(1+i-x)$

which is of the form $P(x)=P(1+i-x)$, therefore $V$ is a vector space.

This seems to me like cheating since I'm assuming that  $P_3 \in V$ but not actually proving it.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: $(f+g)(1+i-x) = f(1+i-x)+g(1+i-x) = f(x)+g(x)$. So it's closed under addition. You seem to have the right idea but its simpler than you think. You need to take two elements in your set and show that the sum of these two elements also lives in your set. The check for closed under scalar multiplication is very similar.

Comment: No sure why you say he condition doesn't make sense.  Constant polynomials clearly satisfy this.  And $P(x)=x(1+i-x)$ satisfies it as well.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts I see, so *by definition* $f(x) + g(x) = (f + g)(x)$, then everything makes sense!

Comment: That is correct. That is literally the definition of addition of two functions.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Great, thanks!